# How do I make a key file undeletable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file, microsoft-file-explorer

I am writing a script that allows users to use a USB stick as a 2FA Login Key on their computer, but if they accidentally delete the key on the USB their computer would potentially permanently log them out, so i would like to make the key file undeletable by the user. Is there a way to set user access rights with a file in python?

Can I make the drive read-only in python, or are there any other solutions to stop the file being deleted? Can I do this in the write of the file below:

```
def create_config(path):
    # Generate random key
    random_key = create_login_key()

    # Write random key and file path to config file
    config = open('config.ini', 'w')
    config.write(f'[DEFAULT]\nRandomKey={random_key}\nFilePath={path}\n')
    config.close()
```

**What I have tried:**

I cannot find any documentation on doing this, except an old python 2.0 stack overflow thread, so I don't know if it is possible in python 3.11 anymore.

Comment: So essentialliy you want to modify permissions of a file on an external drive with python?

Comment: @Ovski yes, that is what i would need